# Dúvida com o firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Como faço para passar este informação para fora do `onDataChange` na mesma atividade tudo dentro do `onCreate`....

```
        mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        String teste = (String) (dataSnapshot.child("texto").getValue());
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Também tenho essa dúvida!!

Comment: estou tendo que fazer um monte de código por causa disso, tipo to usando badge no meu menu drawer, só que não consigo pasar o resultado no oncreate do menu principal, ai tenho que fazer um codigo no login e passar pelo `putExtra` e passar a mesma informação para atividades adjacentes para sempre manter o drawer informado, ta uma porcaria :)

Answer (score 0):

Existe varias formas de resolver esse problema.

1. Melhorando a arquitetura

Você pode aplicar [MVP](https://medium.com/android-dev-br/desmistificando-o-mvc-e-mvp-no-android-abe927d01df7) ou MVVM no seu projeto e modularizar de forma mais eficiente o seu projeto tornando o mais fracamente acoplado, com isso você consegue reutilizar suas camadas de acesso a dados facilmente.

2. Utilizar [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) ou outras bibliotecas similares

Com isso fica fácil a comunicação entre Activities, Fragments, Threads, Services, etc. Você também tem a opção de usar um componente nativo do Android, o `LocalBroadcast` para fazer isso, mas acaba ficando com mais código e complicado.

Comment: ok, vou dar uma olhada nestas dicas ,obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: olá, então olhei estas dicas, entedi +/- como funciona... mais não consegui implementar com firebase... você saberia como fazer?

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é a melhor forma mas funciona.

```
private String mResultadoTeste = null;

private Button mBtnTeste;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_agendamento);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        mBtnTeste = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nome);

        mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


        mResultadoTeste = (String) (dataSnapshot.child("texto").getValue());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    }); 


        mBtnTeste.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                metodo2();

            }
        });

}

    //Fora do OnCreate
    metodo2(){


        Toast.makeText(AgendamentoActivity.this, "Mensagem" +mResultadoTeste, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Comment: preciso que seja feito no oncreate amigo.